# Change background color on active link with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I know there I a lot of questions like this already. But I just can't get this to work.

I want the color to change for the active link using jQuery

```js
 $(function() {
    var links = $('ul li').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('ul').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

```css
    ul.nav a { cursor: pointer; }
    .active { color:#f00;font-weight:bolder; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul class="topmenu">
    <li id="bt" class="active"><a id="btref"  href="#">Sygefravær</a></li>
    <li id="nt"><a id="ntref"  href="#">Nøgletal</a></li>
    <li id="pet"><a id="petref" href="#">Periodeopdelt sygefravær</a></li>
    <li id="frv"><a id="frvref" href="#">Fraværsårsager</a></li>
    <li id="doku"><a href="#">Dokumentation</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close your function });

```js
$(function() {
    var links = $('ul li').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('ul').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });
    });
```

```css
ul.nav a { cursor: pointer; }
    .active { color:#f00;font-weight:bolder; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul class="topmenu">
    <li id="bt" class="active"><a id="btref"  href="#">Sygefravær</a></li>
    <li id="nt"><a id="ntref"  href="#">Nøgletal</a></li>
    <li id="pet"><a id="petref" href="#">Periodeopdelt sygefravær</a></li>
    <li id="frv"><a id="frvref" href="#">Fraværsårsager</a></li>
    <li id="doku"><a href="#">Dokumentation</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```